# Network Manager which hides proxy from applications

Tags: networking, proxy

Is there a network manager similar to the [network manager program](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/NetworkManager) which can handle proxy information (HTTP with **authentication**) and does not require the individual setup of programs; ie. All network requests are directed through to the proxy via the network manager, and the application requires no knowledge of the proxy - they do not even know it is there.

I'm not sure if this is even feasible or not, but it would be really useful so that I do not need to configure proxies.

*system specs:*
Arch Linux, kernel version 4.18.4. If anything more is needed feel free to ask.